# How can I select the first specific inner element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML?

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="./link1">
            <div>something</div>
            <span><a href="./link2">link</a></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this is my jQuery code:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    var link = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
})
```

As you see, there is two `<a>` tags. And `.find()` refersh to both of them. While I just want to select the `<a>` which is right inside *(one level)* in the `<li>` tag. So expected result is `./link`.

What alternative should I use instead of `.find()` ?

Comment: did you try $("li a:eq(0)").attr('href') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the direct descendant selector.

```
$('li').on('click', function(){ var link = $(this).find('> a').attr('href'); })
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with [`eq(0)`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwil3vv0kaLUAhUMK48KHTmFBV0QFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Feq%2F&usg=AFQjCNF421AWRe2A4OnKM21N9XQV5cUFMA&sig2=98DrpUelpITDy5SYVG4hOQ) .It will get the first `a` tag

**Or**

Do with [`first('a')`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjPt82kkqLUAhUKrI8KHUpjDskQFggnMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffirst%2F&usg=AFQjCNF55xumt1xlJ9ZN5YHa1itSQX2PDQ&sig2=OfwKvwlACcLoDAgd6QyW3Q)

```
$(this).children().first('a').attr('href')
```

```js
$('li').click(function(){
console.log($(this).children('a').eq(0).attr('href'))

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>click
        <a href="./link1">
            <div>something</div>
            <span><a href="./link2">link</a></span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Don't think you need the `.eq(0)` -- the `children()` already covers it. He's only got one at that level.

Comment: @mpen Yes `children` cover all the childrens .for more specific  i was added with `eq(0)`

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Using Jquery's `children` and `first`**

```js
$('#myList').on('click', function() {
  var link = $('#myList').children('a').first();
  console.log(link.attr('href'));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="myList">
    <a href="./link1">
      <div>something</div>
      <span><a href="./link2">link</a></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Method 2: Using the immediate children selector `>`**

```js
$('#myList').on('click', function() {
  var link = $('li > a:first');
  console.log(link.attr("href"));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="myList">
    <a href="./link1">
      <div>something</div>
      <span><a href="./link2">link</a></span>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

> the first specific element
>
> What alternative should I use instead of .find() ?

```
$(this).find('a:first')
```

seems like only logical solution and easy to read by developer

Answer (score 0):

Don't do so. How is the browser meant to know which link to follow? It'd be invalid HTML

I suggest you using this instead:

```
<a href="page1">start</a><a href="page2">middle</a><a href="page1">end</a>
```

As you can see start and end are linked to page1 but the middle points to page2.